# Python interprets '.' as a string when reading numeric data from a csv file, I want to do math operations on float variables

Tags: python, csv, object, replace, dtype

I have this code:

```
stirs=pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Research/SOMA/FRED_reserves/SOMArates4.csv',na_values=" ", thousands='.', usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5],parse_dates=['DATE']).fillna(value=0)
```

The resulting Dataframe represents some of the data as `object`, where I want `float` results instead.

I tried this but it did not fix the problem. I still get data as `object` dtype.

```
stirs=pd.read_csv(r'C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Research/SOMA/FRED_reserves/`SOMArates4.csv', na_values=" ", usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5],dtype={'RPONTSYD': float, 'RRPONTSYD': float, 'RPTSYD':  float, 'EFFR': float}, parse_dates=['DATE']).fillna(value=0)
```

Next, I tried to replace '.' values with `np.nan`:

```
stirs.replace('.', np.nan, None, regex=True)  
stirs.info() 
stirs.dtypes
```

The resulting dtypes are:

```
     #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype  
    ---  ------     --------------  -----  
     0   DATE       1306 non-null   datetime64[ns]  
     1   RPONTSYD   1306 non-null   object  
     2   RRPONTSYD  1306 non-null   object  
     3   RPTSYD     1306 non-null   object  
     4   RRPTSYD    1306 non-null   object  
     5   EFFR       1306 non-null   object
```

I found the specific reason for the error. I tried changing the data to numeric with this code:

```
stirs["RPONTSYD"] = pd.to_numeric(stirs["RPONTSYD"])  
stirs["RRPONTSYD"] = pd.to_numeric(stirs["RRPONTSYD"])  
stirs["RPTSYD"] = pd.to_numeric(stirs["RPTSYD"])  
stirs["RRPTSYD"] = pd.to_numeric(stirs["RRPTSYD"])  
stirs["EFFR"] = pd.to_numeric(stirs["EFFR"])
```

but get the error message: `ValueError: Unable to parse string "." at position 0`.

Here are a few lines of the input, for reference:

```
DATE    RPONTSYD    RRPONTSYD   RPTSYD  RRPTSYD EFFR  
5/16/2017   .   .   .   .   0.91  
5/17/2017   .   167.158 .   167.158 0.91  
5/18/2017   .   185.287 .   185.287 0.91  
5/19/2017   .   182.273 .   182.273 0.91  
5/22/2017   .   185.031 .   185.031 0.91
```

How can I change the date in cols 1-5 from *object* to *float* (col 0 is the date)?

Comment: Before asking this question on stackoverflow, how to change type from string to float, in order to perform analysis, I tried: stirs.replace('.', np.nan, None, regex=True). Python rejected later attempts to change variable class from object or string as well. Finally I found the issue was specificial cells filled with '." which Python interpreted as strings and none of the above methods worked to change to float.

Comment: I tried: s = stirs["EFFR"]
f = []
for item in s:
    f.append(float(item))
print(f)  But got error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'

Answer (score 0):

Rather than changing the dtype, it would be better to get the correct dtype in the first place. As explained [in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> na_values : *scalar, str, list-like, or dict, optional*

> Additional strings to recognize as NA/NaN. If dict passed, specific per-column NA values. By default the following values are interpreted as NaN: ‘’, ‘#N/A’, ‘#N/A N/A’, ‘#NA’, ‘-1.#IND’, ‘-1.#QNAN’, ‘-NaN’, ‘-nan’, ‘1.#IND’, ‘1.#QNAN’, ‘’, ‘N/A’, ‘NA’, ‘NULL’, ‘NaN’, ‘n/a’, ‘nan’, ‘null’.

In this case, we want cells that contain `.` to be interpreted as empty, so we use that as for the `na_values`. Thus:

```
stirs = pd.read_csv(filename, na_values=".", usecols=[0,1,2,3,4,5], parse_dates=['DATE']).fillna(value=0)
```

The `na_values` in the original code did not make sense for this application. (I also assume that you do not actually want to use `.` as a thousands separator in the data, but instead expect `.` to be a decimal point per the usual North American interpretation.) I do not have your exact file, but with the test file I attempted to reproduce, I was able to get

```
        DATE  RPONTSYD  RRPONTSYD  RPTSYD  RRPTSYD  EFFR
0 2017-05-16       0.0      0.000     0.0    0.000  0.91
1 2017-05-17       0.0    167.158     0.0  167.158  0.91
2 2017-05-18       0.0    185.287     0.0  185.287  0.91
3 2017-05-19       0.0    182.273     0.0  182.273  0.91
4 2017-05-22       0.0    185.031     0.0  185.031  0.91
```

with the appropriate column types:

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 6 columns):
 #   Column     Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------     --------------  -----         
 0   DATE       5 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   RPONTSYD   5 non-null      float64       
 2   RRPONTSYD  5 non-null      float64       
 3   RPTSYD     5 non-null      float64       
 4   RRPTSYD    5 non-null      float64       
 5   EFFR       5 non-null      float64       
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(5)
memory usage: 368.0 bytes
```

---

Next, let's see what went wrong:

> I tried to replace '.' values with np.nan:

This only solves half the problem: the `.`s get replaced with a valid floating-point value, but the remaining values are still *strings* - because Pandas could not deduce a `float` datatype when it was loading the data. (Also, using `regex=True` like this will replace every string *that contains* `.`, including valid data.)

> I tried changing the data to numeric with this code

The `.` isn't valid input to convert to float, so this fails. However, *after* replacing the `.`s with NaN, it should be possible to convert the column to float.

All that was needed, then, was to use both of these steps, in that order.